# Repetition of pronouns together with verbs or nouns in one sentence

Tags: gramática

I was wondering - if there are several verbs/nouns in one sentence and also I want to use any pronoun (direct object pronoun, indirect object pronoun, demonstrative pronoun, etc.), do I HAVE to ALWAYS repeat pronoun with each verb? Should it be like in case of definite articles (example below)? Or you can use several verbs and attach pronoun to first verb only (if you like)?

*We're selling **the** house and chair. = Vendemos **la** casa y **la** silla.*

My guess is that for some pronouns you are NOT required to attach the same pronoun to each verb/noun, but you CAN attach (IF you like), for the purpose of making the overall sentence sounding more "stronger".
But this is only guess. So far I saw for DO (direct object) pronoun that it is repeated (example below):

From Movie Venganza (Taken), year 2008:  "*Si no lo hace, **le** buscaré, **le** encontraré y **le** mataré.*" [here is an apparent case of Leísmo (should be "lo" in all cases), but this is a different topic.]

I am asking about all the types of pronouns (for example, demonstrative "esta" with nouns, possesive pronouns with nouns), not only DO or IO pronouns.

For example, in a sentence below which I came up with myself, I believe I have to attach possessive pronouns to both nouns and it will be correct:

*These are **my** chair and table - Estas son **mi** silla y **mi** mesa*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that most of your examples are not *pronouns* but *determinants*. Pronouns replace a noun; determinants introduce and accompany it.

That said, the answer in both cases is **yes**:

- if one verb affects several nouns, each noun must have its corresponding determinant. This is not even repeating, as different nouns might require different determinants:

  > He comprado **esta** mesa y **esta** silla.
  >
  > He traído **el** bolígrafo y **la** pluma.
- if several verbs apply to the same object, and this object is a pronoun, then the pronoun must be repeated next to every verb:

  > Me **lo** encontré en la calle, **lo** miré y **lo** abracé.

  Furthermore, if several verbs apply to the same object and the object is a noun, all verbs that come *after* the noun must have the pronoun:

  > Escribe la carta, fírma**la**, méte**la** en un sobre y envía**la**.

  However, verbs that come *before* the noun they refer to do not require a pronoun:

  > Escribe, firma y envía la carta.

**Note:** in some very specific cases, when the two verbs or the two nouns are very closely related, it might be possible to omit the pronoun/determinant in the second one:

> **Tus** sillas y mesas son todas nuevas.
>
> **Lo** juzgaron y condenaron por asesinato.

As far as I know, these are indeed *very* specific cases, and repeating the pronoun/determinant is also allowed in these cases. Repeating is always a safe choice.

Comment: I wonder about the plural situation for your first bullet, though -- maybe *¿Tus sillas y mesas son todas nuevas??

Comment: @aparente001 mmm that does work. But it seems to only work when the objects are closely related. Would you say *Tus sillas y tazas son todas nuevas*?

Comment: No, good point.  I agree, they have to be closely related, and even then the combining seems optional.  What about this?  *¿Lo saludas y abrazas de mi parte, por favor?*  If that works, it would only be because they're so closely connected.

Comment: @aparente001 I updated the answer. Language is indeed a difficult beast to tame!

Comment: It's so interesting, learners' questions can make one think about things in a new way. // I like your juzgaron y condenaron example.